# Passing URL using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Suppose that I have a URL like the following:

```
http://localhost:8000/intranet/users/view?user_id=8823
```

Now, all I want to do is to get the value of the URL using JavaScript and parse it, taking the `user_id` value (which is 8823 in this case) and sending that value through an `iframe`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
function getParameterByName(name)
{ 
      name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]"); 
      var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"; 
      var regex = new RegExp(regexS); 
      var results = regex.exec(window.location.href); 

   if(results == null) 
      return ""; 
   else 
   return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " ")); 
}
```

i found it at [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Try using window.location.href or document.URL

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
var matches = document.location.search.match( /user_id=(\d+)/ );
if ( matches != null )
{
    alert( matches[ 1 ] );
}
```

matches[ 1 ] will contain the user ID.
document.location.search contains the query string (all of the parameters which follow the '?' including the '?').

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = "http://localhost:8000/intranet/users/view?user_id=8823";
//var url = document.URL;
var url = test.split("=");
var urlID = url[url.length-1];

document.write(urlID);

window.frames["myIframe"].yourMethod(urlID);
```